# Trying to count SharePoint List Values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, validation, sharepoint, count

Hello stack overflow community...

Thanks for all of the help that you have provided so far even though I have never posted on this site.  I am a beginner... so that means most of the stuff that I have gotten to work has come after trying to shove a square peg into a round hole too many times to count until finally the edges are worn off enough that it actually fits...

Anyway... due to the Today() issue with SharePoint and the need to base data comparison against the current date/time I have been struggling to write my own code and display the data as I would like to in the SharePoint site that I have access too.

So far I have everything working as intended with one little flaw...

I cannot figure out how to count values even though I can make comparisons between two values.  I believe it has something to do with how data is being retrieved from the SharePoint list rows and appended to the HTML table.

Relevant sections of code are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    CAMLRowLimit: 20,
    listName: "Announcements",
    completefunc: FirstFunc
    });
});

function FirstFunc(xData, Status) {
var index = 0;
$documentListtable = $("#tableFirstFunc");

$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {


var LOTOSPLink =$(this).attr("ows_LOTODocLink");
var _Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
var ahref = "<a href='" + LOTOSPLink + "'>";
var anchor = "</a>"
var Titles = ahref + _Title + anchor

    //Start of AReview

var _AReview = $(this).attr("ows_AReview");
var astartDateTime = $(this).attr("ows_AReview");
var astartDate = $(this).attr("ows_AReview").split(" ")[0];
var astartTime = $(this).attr("ows_AReview").split(" ")[1];

var astartDateParts = astartDate.split("-");
var aSPDYear = astartDateParts[0];
var aSPDMonth = astartDateParts[1];
var aSPDDay = astartDateParts[2];

var aSPDJoin = aSPDMonth+'/'+aSPDDay+'/'+aSPDYear;

var astartTimeParts = astartTime.split(":");
var aSPTHour = astartTimeParts[0];
var aSPTMin = astartTimeParts[1];
var aSPTSec = astartTimeParts[2];

    //Combine SharePoint Date & Time split parts back together in JS Date Object 
                //format and than convert to millisecons to compare dates

        var aReviewGraphic = ""
  if(aSPDTValue === 18000000) {
    aReviewGraphic="<img src="sites/Somesite/NAGlassyButton20.png>";
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue >= firstDCMonth && aSPDTValue < lastDCMonth) {
    aReviewGraphic="<img src="/sites/Somesite/GreenButtNew20.png>";
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue >= firstDCYear && aSPDTValue < firstDCMonth) {
    aReviewGraphic="<img src="/sites/Somesite//GreenButtOld20.png>";
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue < firstDCYear) {
    aReviewGraphic="<img src="/sites/Somesite/RedButt20.png>";
    }

var $row = $("#templates").find(".row-template").clone();

$row.find(".Titles").html(Titles);
$row.find(".aReviewGraphic").html(aReviewGraphic);
$row.find(".bReviewGraphic").html(bReviewGraphic);
$row.find(".cReviewGraphic").html(cReviewGraphic);
$row.find(".dReviewGraphic").html(dReviewGraphic);
$row.find(".NewModiDReviewGraphic").html(NewModiDReviewGraphic);

$documentListtable.append($row);

});

}
```

I am changing the graphics in the tables as intended, the data is being displayed as desired... but I cannot figure out how to perform a count.  It seems like the rows are being read one at a time and being put into the HTML table one after the other and that all comparisons are being done row by row.  I say that because my alert(messages) are being triggered for each row of data pulled in from the sharepoint list.

Is there a way to store this data in an array locally... surely there is some way to do this but I am new enough to this that I don't even know the right questions to ask...

Also the 18000000 in the if statement is the 1/1/1970 test date that I am using to currently test with as I found that any fields that were blank in the sharepoint list would cause the query to quit returning any rows after that.  My solution was to use the 1/1/1970 as the default value and use it the same as leaving the field blank.  I am sure that this is a crude method to work a round a problem that is easy to fix but it was all I could come up with.

Any help would be appreciated... 
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand... My suggestion is to store all your html into a variable and then inject the code into the table.

```
// somewhere you should have your HTML code
// <table id="templates"></table>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    CAMLRowLimit: 20,
    listName: "Announcements",
    completefunc: FirstFunc
  });
});

function FirstFunc(xData, Status) {
  var index = 0;
  $documentListtable = $("#tableFirstFunc");
  // create a variable where to store the html code
  var htmlData = "";
  // go thru the data received by the query
  $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
    // we look at one row
    var LOTOSPLink =$(this).attr("ows_LOTODocLink");
    var _Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
    var ahref = "<a href='" + LOTOSPLink + "'>";
    var anchor = "</a>"
    var Titles = ahref + _Title + anchor

    //Start of AReview
    var _AReview = $(this).attr("ows_AReview");
    var astartDateTime = $(this).attr("ows_AReview");
    var astartDate = $(this).attr("ows_AReview").split(" ")[0];
    var astartTime = $(this).attr("ows_AReview").split(" ")[1];

    var astartDateParts = astartDate.split("-");
    var aSPDYear = astartDateParts[0];
    var aSPDMonth = astartDateParts[1];
    var aSPDDay = astartDateParts[2];

    var aSPDJoin = aSPDMonth+'/'+aSPDDay+'/'+aSPDYear;

    var astartTimeParts = astartTime.split(":");
    var aSPTHour = astartTimeParts[0];
    var aSPTMin = astartTimeParts[1];
    var aSPTSec = astartTimeParts[2];

    //Combine SharePoint Date & Time split parts back together in JS Date Object 
    //format and than convert to millisecons to compare dates

    var aReviewGraphic = "";
    // I don't understand why you use this variable that hasn't been initialized...
    if (aSPDTValue === 18000000) {
      aReviewGraphic='<img src="sites/Somesite/NAGlassyButton20.png>';
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue >= firstDCMonth && aSPDTValue < lastDCMonth) {
      aReviewGraphic='<img src="/sites/Somesite/GreenButtNew20.png>';
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue >= firstDCYear && aSPDTValue < firstDCMonth) {
      aReviewGraphic='<img src="/sites/Somesite//GreenButtOld20.png>';
    }
    else if(aSPDTValue < firstDCYear) {
      aReviewGraphic='<img src="/sites/Somesite/RedButt20.png>';
    }

    htmlData += '<tr><td class="Titles">'+Titles+'</td><td class="aReviewGraphic">'+aReviewGraphic+'</td><td class="bReviewGraphic">'+bReviewGraphic+'</td><td class="cReviewGraphic">'+cReviewGraphic+'</td><td class="dReviewGraphic">'+dReviewGraphic+'</td><td class="NewModiDReviewGraphic">'+NewModiDReviewGraphic+'</td></tr>';

    // you can increment your index if you want
    index++;
  });

  alert("There are "+index+" rows");
  // add the HTML data into the table
  $documentListtable.append(htmlData);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the undefined variable when I was copying and pasting sections of my code I left off two lines.  Right below the comment line before the "if statements there is:

Comment: var aSPDTtoJSDT = new Date(aSPDYear, (aSPDMonth - 1), aSPDDay, aSPTHour, aSPTMin, aSPTSec, 00);  <br>                                   
 var aSPDTValue = aSPDTtoJSDT.valueOf();

Comment: I will let you know if this works.  So far I have not been able to get this to append into my table in this manner.  The index++ is working though and is alerting me to the number of rows (thanks for that :D) but the data is not showing up.

Comment: OK... well still haven't been able to get it to append correctly but I have the rest of the night to work on it.  Still one question remains, and was the reason that I posted... how will this help me to count values in columns.  I can get the count of the rows, but what about the date values in the columns.

Comment: What do you want to count ? The number of rows with a Red/Green buttons ?

Comment: Been very busy at work and so have not had time to work on this since posting this.  SHould have more time to get back to this project next month.

Comment: AymKdn... No I do not want to count the rows with red or green buttons.  I want to count the number of red buttons in a column and count the number of green buttons in a column.